# How should i release signal-slot in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing simple program with signal-slot where if I increment or decrement value in one counter, it will be incremented and decremented in other counter by using slots and signals.
I made slots private, so we can't use them from outside and called signals from simple methods(non-slots). Is it normal realization in qt philosophy? I don't like both Increment() method and releaseIncrement() doing the same job, can i somehow avoid this? And is it normal to keep slots as private? This is my code:

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Counter(int startValue);
    int Increment();
    int Decrement();
    void printValue();

private slots:
    void releaseIncrement();
    void releaseDecrement();

signals:
    void wasIncremented();
    void wasDecremented();

private:
    int m_count;
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

```
#include "counter.h"
#include <iostream>

Counter::Counter(int startValue)
{
    m_count = startValue;
}

void Counter::printValue()
{
    std::cout <<"value is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
}

int Counter::Increment()
{
    m_count++;
    std::cout <<"m_count was incremented by Increment() method. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
    emit wasIncremented();
    return m_count;
}

int Counter::Decrement()
{
    m_count--;
    std::cout <<"m_count was decremented by Decrement() method. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
    emit wasDecremented();
    return m_count;
}

void Counter::releaseIncrement()
{
    m_count++;
    std::cout <<"m_count was incremented by releaseIncrement() slot. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
}

void Counter::releaseDecrement()
{
    std::cout <<"m_count was decremented by releaseDecrement() method. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
    m_count--;
}
```

````
int main()
{
    Counter a(0);
    Counter b(10);

    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(wasIncremented()), &b, SLOT(releaseIncrement()));
    QObject::connect(&b, SIGNAL(wasIncremented()), &a, SLOT(releaseIncrement()));
    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(wasDecremented()), &b, SLOT(releaseDecrement()));
    QObject::connect(&b, SIGNAL(wasDecremented()), &a, SLOT(releaseDecrement()));
}```
````

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "release". One simplification you could make is to have `Increment` directly call `releaseIncrement`. But I still don't really get what the goal is.

Comment: @drescherjm But if i will place emit signal in slot method it will be infinite loop. so i separated them into simple method which emits and slot which not emits. Is it weird?

Comment: @drescherjm my bad, edited. I mean if i will remove Increment() and Decrement() and place emiters in slots I will get infinite loop. Like when releaseIncrement() used on a, then releaseIncrement() is invoked on b which calls wasIncremented() and invokes releaseIncrement() on a and so on...

Comment: ADV were your comments directed at me?  If so, you misunderstood my suggestion. I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't really understand your question. But I can offer help on this part of your question:

> I don't like both Increment() method and releaseIncrement() doing the same job, can i somehow avoid this?

Yes, you can avoid it by calling the slots directly from the public functions, like this:

```
int Counter::Increment()
{
    releaseIncrement();
    emit wasIncremented();
    return m_count;
}

int Counter::Decrement()
{
    releaseDecrement();
    emit wasDecremented();
    return m_count;
}

void Counter::releaseIncrement()
{
    m_count++;
    std::cout <<"m_count was incremented by releaseIncrement() slot. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
}

void Counter::releaseDecrement()
{
    std::cout <<"m_count was decremented by releaseDecrement() method. Now m_count is: " <<m_count <<std::endl;
    m_count--;
}
```